# ¿Cómo operar con valores sacados de una select vb?

Tags: vb.net, select2

Buenas a todos, quería preguntaros si es posible sacar un valor de una select para operar con el en vb.
Tengo un programa que se encarga de llevar compras, ventas, existencias...
en la tabla productos tengo un campo que es precio, y en la tabla ventas tengo dos campos que son, cantidad y precio total.

Pues he intentado hacer que dependiendo de la cantidad que pongas, te multiplique ese precio por la cantidad pero no soy capaz de sacar el precio para poder operar con el.
He intentado con un select into y nada, he intentado hacerlo desde la propia select y nada.

Alguna idea de como podría hacerlo?
Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: necesitamos más información para ayudarte: cuál es el código que intentaste utilizar, que tipo de aplicación es (winforms/wpf/asp.net), sin más información es bastante difícil elaborar una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: Qué base de datos utilizas?